# How should I deserialize this object properly?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is probably an easy one, apologies in advance. I'm just getting frustrated with it and my JSON tolerance wavers depending on the day.

The string deserializes fine for the key but when the Quote object tries to deserialize there is no luck. The Quote object gets constructed but all of the values are null/defaulted to their object's null value (0 for int/double, null for string, etc.). The "quote" property isn't getting deserialized to the object.

I tried

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Quote>>
```

With "Quote" being the following:

```
    [JsonObject("quote")]
    public class Quote
    {
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        public string primaryExchange { get; set; }
        public string sector { get; set; }
        public string calculationPrice { get; set; }
        public float open { get; set; }
        public long openTime { get; set; }
        public float close { get; set; }
        public long closeTime { get; set; }
        public float high { get; set; }
        public float low { get; set; }
        public float latestPrice { get; set; }
        public string latestSource { get; set; }
        public string latestTime { get; set; }
        public long latestUpdate { get; set; }
        public int latestVolume { get; set; }
        public float iexRealtimePrice { get; set; }
        public int iexRealtimeSize { get; set; }
        public long iexLastUpdated { get; set; }
        public float delayedPrice { get; set; }
        public long delayedPriceTime { get; set; }
        public float previousClose { get; set; }
        public float change { get; set; }
        public float changePercent { get; set; }
        public float iexMarketPercent { get; set; }
        public int iexVolume { get; set; }
        public int avgTotalVolume { get; set; }
        public float iexBidPrice { get; set; }
        public int iexBidSize { get; set; }
        public float iexAskPrice { get; set; }
        public int iexAskSize { get; set; }
        public long marketCap { get; set; }
        public float peRatio { get; set; }
        public float week52High { get; set; }
        public float week52Low { get; set; }
        public float ytdChange { get; set; }
    }
```

The JSON looks as follows:

```
{
  "AMAT": {
    "quote": {
      "symbol": "AMAT",
      "companyName": "Applied Materials Inc.",
      "primaryExchange": "Nasdaq Global Select",
      "sector": "Technology",
      "calculationPrice": "tops",
      "open": 55.87,
      "openTime": 1520001000554,
      "close": 57.07,
      "closeTime": 1519938000425,
      "high": 57.619,
      "low": 55.12,
      "latestPrice": 57.65,
      "latestSource": "IEX real time price",
      "latestTime": "12:56:33 PM",
      "latestUpdate": 1520013393045,
      "latestVolume": 8005359,
      "iexRealtimePrice": 57.65,
      "iexRealtimeSize": 100,
      "iexLastUpdated": 1520013393045,
      "delayedPrice": 57.42,
      "delayedPriceTime": 1520012500382,
      "previousClose": 57.07,
      "change": 0.58,
      "changePercent": 0.01016,
      "iexMarketPercent": 0.03564,
      "iexVolume": 285311,
      "avgTotalVolume": 16065459,
      "iexBidPrice": 56.06,
      "iexBidSize": 100,
      "iexAskPrice": 58.63,
      "iexAskSize": 100,
      "marketCap": 60572134433,
      "peRatio": 17.74,
      "week52High": 60.89,
      "week52Low": 36.33,
      "ytdChange": 0.075980392156863
    }
  },
  "AAPL": {
    "quote": {
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "companyName": "Apple Inc.",
      "primaryExchange": "Nasdaq Global Select",
      "sector": "Technology",
      "calculationPrice": "tops",
      "open": 172.67,
      "openTime": 1520001000489,
      "close": 175,
      "closeTime": 1519938000498,
      "high": 175.67,
      "low": 172.45,
      "latestPrice": 175.92,
      "latestSource": "IEX real time price",
      "latestTime": "12:56:35 PM",
      "latestUpdate": 1520013395847,
      "latestVolume": 21945163,
      "iexRealtimePrice": 175.92,
      "iexRealtimeSize": 100,
      "iexLastUpdated": 1520013395847,
      "delayedPrice": 175.299,
      "delayedPriceTime": 1520012500554,
      "previousClose": 175,
      "change": 0.92,
      "changePercent": 0.00526,
      "iexMarketPercent": 0.03742,
      "iexVolume": 821188,
      "avgTotalVolume": 45362032,
      "iexBidPrice": 173,
      "iexBidSize": 200,
      "iexAskPrice": 175.89,
      "iexAskSize": 100,
      "marketCap": 892620366960,
      "peRatio": 19.12,
      "week52High": 180.615,
      "week52Low": 137.05,
      "ytdChange": 0.015906188319981
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific about the problem.

Comment: What does “there is no luck” mean?

Comment: This thing is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.  You said "hey, for quote objects, put them in a quote key in my JSON."

Comment: Added details. My bad, spent too much time on getting the code copied over and forgot to add better details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to different objects i.e `AMAT` & `AAPL`:

```
public class ToBeDeserialized
{
    public AMAT AMAT { get; set; }
    public AAPL AAPL { get; set; }
}

public class AMAT
{
    public Quote quote { get; set; }
}

public class AAPL
{
    public Quote quote { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public string primaryExchange { get; set; }
    public string sector { get; set; }
    public string calculationPrice { get; set; }
    public float open { get; set; }
    public long openTime { get; set; }
    public float close { get; set; }
    public long closeTime { get; set; }
    public float high { get; set; }
    public float low { get; set; }
    public float latestPrice { get; set; }
    public string latestSource { get; set; }
    public string latestTime { get; set; }
    public long latestUpdate { get; set; }
    public int latestVolume { get; set; }
    public float iexRealtimePrice { get; set; }
    public int iexRealtimeSize { get; set; }
    public long iexLastUpdated { get; set; }
    public float delayedPrice { get; set; }
    public long delayedPriceTime { get; set; }
    public float previousClose { get; set; }
    public float change { get; set; }
    public float changePercent { get; set; }
    public float iexMarketPercent { get; set; }
    public int iexVolume { get; set; }
    public int avgTotalVolume { get; set; }
    public float iexBidPrice { get; set; }
    public int iexBidSize { get; set; }
    public float iexAskPrice { get; set; }
    public int iexAskSize { get; set; }
    public long marketCap { get; set; }
    public float peRatio { get; set; }
    public float week52High { get; set; }
    public float week52Low { get; set; }
    public float ytdChange { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize it like below:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToBeDeserialized>(json);
```

**Output:**

[image]

### UPDATE:

As per OP's comment, I have used another class below to deserialize:

```
public class ToBeDeserialized
{
    public Quote quote { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public string primaryExchange { get; set; }
    public string sector { get; set; }
    public string calculationPrice { get; set; }
    public float open { get; set; }
    public long openTime { get; set; }
    public float close { get; set; }
    public long closeTime { get; set; }
    public float high { get; set; }
    public float low { get; set; }
    public float latestPrice { get; set; }
    public string latestSource { get; set; }
    public string latestTime { get; set; }
    public long latestUpdate { get; set; }
    public int latestVolume { get; set; }
    public float iexRealtimePrice { get; set; }
    public int iexRealtimeSize { get; set; }
    public long iexLastUpdated { get; set; }
    public float delayedPrice { get; set; }
    public long delayedPriceTime { get; set; }
    public float previousClose { get; set; }
    public float change { get; set; }
    public float changePercent { get; set; }
    public float iexMarketPercent { get; set; }
    public int iexVolume { get; set; }
    public int avgTotalVolume { get; set; }
    public float iexBidPrice { get; set; }
    public int iexBidSize { get; set; }
    public float iexAskPrice { get; set; }
    public int iexAskSize { get; set; }
    public long marketCap { get; set; }
    public float peRatio { get; set; }
    public float week52High { get; set; }
    public float week52Low { get; set; }
    public float ytdChange { get; set; }
}
```

And get a list of quotes like:

```
private static List<ToBeDeserialized> DeserializeAccordingly(string json)
{
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    IDictionary<string, JToken> quotes = data;
    List<ToBeDeserialized> listOfQuote = new List<ToBeDeserialized>();
    foreach (var quote in quotes)
    {
        var qu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToBeDeserialized>(quote.Value.ToString());
        listOfQuote.Add(qu);
    }
    return listOfQuote;
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that, if I get more values, I'll have to add each symbol to the ToBeDeserialized if I'm not mistaken? I wanted to return a list of all the symbols and iterate through that later if possible.

Comment: @PhillipMcMullen there are two different `quotes` in your JSON, one belongs to `AMAT` other to `AAPL`, how can you make a single list out of it? If there was a common name then it would have been possible, but in this case they have two different names.

Comment: Yea it looks like their JSON is just formatted in a way that I'll need to loop through grabbing by key from a separate list of tickers. Thank you though for your answer as it was one of the only ones that was productive

Comment: @PhillipMcMullen I have another idea, please bear with me.

Comment: @PhillipMcMullen Please see my updated answer, hope it helps you.